# How to roll up a column with a query

Tags: ms-access

i have an acess "query" that consist of Drawing-title and Multiple data per ID. And i would like to roll up this data into separate columns. Thanks in advance.

My query looks like this
[image: My query looks like this]

And would like to change to this
[image: And would like to change to this]

Comment: Use the _Crosstab query_ wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CROSSTAB requires 3 fields. You need to calculate a third field as a sequence number for each group that will become RowHeader. This will require a unique identifier field in table - autonumber should serve.

```
TRANSFORM First(Data) AS FirstData
SELECT DWG
FROM tableORquery
GROUP BY DWG
PIVOT  DCount("*","tableORquery","DWG='" & [DWG] & "' And ID<" & [ID])+1;
```

Comment: is it possible to change the output data to its original sequence and not alphabetically?

Comment: Don't understand. The original sequence is alphabetic in example.